# Looking for an easy option to change the title of a SelfAssertedAttributeProvider UI

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a technical profile that asks use a simple question. Here is the definition:

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method">
      <DisplayName>Allow user to choose their MFA Method</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" Required="true"/>
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Above technical profile shows the following UI:

[image]

Is there an easy option to change the header text"**Update your current profile**" in the above TechnicalProfile XML definition?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-configure-user-input

Comment: @ChauncyZhou, no. I updated the screenshot. I am not updating the claim labels. I need to update the dialog header pointed with a red arrow in the screenshot in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use language customisation, the id will be initial_intro
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-and-self-asserted-pages-user-interface-elements

Comment: thank you for help. This looks a perfect option. But initial_intro did not work, seems belong to a diffrent content. I am not able to find the localization ID I am looking for. I marked this as answer as I know it will help others. I posted a more specific question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016490/b2c-custom-policies-how-to-find-undocumented-localization-string-id-for-the-jur