# B2C Custom Policies: How to find undocumented Localization string ID for the jurney UI headers

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have the following technical profile in my user jurnet that produces the UI shown below:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method">
  <DisplayName>Allow user to choose their MFA Method</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" Required="true"/>
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

[image]

I need to change the message "Update your current profile" to something meaningful or removing it.

Through this SO question ([Looking for an easy option to change the title of a SelfAssertedAttributeProvider UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997758/looking-for-an-easy-option-to-change-the-title-of-a-selfassertedattributeprovide/64004267#64004267)) I learned that the best way of doing it is to use localizations documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-and-self-asserted-pages-user-interface-elements

Unfortunately above page does not list any Localization string ID for the message "Update your current profile" pointed above.

What is the localization id for the message "Update your current profile" pointed above?

Is there any way to find the undocumented localization ids by looking at the UI's HTML source or disassembling a DLL?

**Update 1:**

@juunas approach looked promissing, but there is not trace of the "Update your current profile" message there.

```
{
    "ver_success_screenreader_msg": "E-mail address verified. You can now continue.",
    "month": "Month",
    "ver_but_default": "Default",
    "ver_fail_server": "We are having trouble verifying your email address. Please enter a valid email address and try again.",
    "ver_intro_msg": "Verification is necessary. Please click Send button.",
    "ver_fail_throttled": "There have been too many requests to verify this email address. Please wait a while, then try again.",
    "months": "January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December",
    "ver_input": "Verification code",
    "ver_fail_retry": "That code is incorrect. Please try again.",
    "error_requiredFieldMissing": "A required field is missing. Please fill out all required fields and try again.",
    "error_passwordEntryMismatch": "The password entry fields do not match. Please enter the same password in both fields and try again.",
    "helplink_text": "What is this?",
    "alert_yes": "Yes",
    "ver_sent": "Verification code has been sent to:",
    "verifying_blurb": "Please wait while we process your information.",
    "ver_but_edit": "Change e-mail",
    "ver_but_send": "Send verification code",
    "ver_success_msg": "E-mail address verified. You can now continue.",
    "cancel_message": "The user has cancelled entering self-asserted information",
    "ver_incorrect_format": "Incorect format.",
    "error_fieldIncorrect": "One or more fields are filled out incorrectly. Please check your entries and try again.",
    "alert_message": "Are you sure that you want to cancel entering your details?",
    "button_continue": "Continue",
    "alert_title": "Cancel Entering Your Details",
    "ver_fail_no_retry": "You&#39;ve made too many incorrect attempts. Please try again later.",
    "alert_no": "No",
    "preloader_alt": "Please wait",
    "ver_fail_code_expired": "That code is expired. Please request a new code.",
    "button_cancel": "Cancel",
    "ver_info_msg": "Verification code has been sent to your inbox. Please copy it to the input box below.",
    "ver_but_verify": "Verify code",
    "required_field": "This information is required.",
    "ver_but_resend": "Send new code",
    "initial_intro": "Please provide the following details.",
    "year": "Year",
    "day": "Day"
}
```

Yet the message is in the HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've usually found the localized strings in a script element in the `<head>` part of the page.
It looks something like this:

```html
<script data-container="true" nonce="">
var SA_FIELDS = {
  "AttributeFields": [
    {
      "UX_INPUT_TYPE": "TextBox",
      "USER_INPUT_TYPE": "TextBox"
    }
  ]
};


var CONTENT = {
  "ver_success_screenreader_msg": "E-mail address verified. You can now continue.",
  "month": "Month",
  "ver_but_default": "Default",
  "ver_fail_server": "We are having trouble verifying your email address. Please enter a valid email address and try again.",
  "ver_intro_msg": "Verification is necessary. Please click Send button."
};
</script>
```

The `CONTENT` variable there contains the localized strings.
You can also see its content by typing `CONTENT` in the browser console.

Comment: This is a promissing approach, but please see my update. I can't find any trace of that message excep the <h3> inner text. Thought?